# Trim one object in the shape of another object in Blender?

Tags: mesh

[image]

As shown in the image. Is there a graceful way where I can trim the excess portion of planks and just have the inner planks remaining that's inside of the boat? (I could not do this with boolean myself, if it is possible then please do tell.)

I hope i am explaining myself clearly. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any magic way, just go in Edit mode and move the vertices along the edges until they are good

Comment: Just after posting the question I figured it out myself. And yes there is a graceful way without having to go into edit mode and edit each and every plank. It's Blender afterall. The answer is - 1. Join every plank (Ctrl+J) 2. Add boolean 'difference' using the boat as the object. 3. Once it cuts the "boat" shape from the "plank" just delete the excess portions. Then you are left with a clean planks following the contour of the boat! That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting the question I figured it out myself. And yes there is a graceful way without having to go into edit mode and edit each and every plank. It's Blender afterall. The answer is - 1. Join every plank (Ctrl+J) 2. Add boolean 'difference' using the boat as the object. 3. Once it cuts the "boat" shape from the "plank" just delete the excess portions. Then you are left with a clean planks following the contour of the boat! That's it!

[image]